# Count SetCookie via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, cookies, setcookie

I am trying to implement "ADD TO SHORTLIST" via php/ajax

Here's my relevant codes

**Calling ajax from this page** :

```
<a id="shortlist" class="pull-right add-to-shortlist">Add to shortlist</a>
<p id="cookieShortList"><?=$_COOKIE['shortlist_count']?></p>

<script>

$("#shortlist").click(function(){ 
     $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "ajaxcall.php",
        data:{spId : "111",prId : "222"},
        success: function(result) 
        {
            $('#cookieShortList').html(result);
        }
   });
});

</script>
```

**POST DATA page**:

```
$s_id = $_REQUEST['spId'];
$product_id = $_REQUEST['prId'];

setcookie("cookie_product[$s_id]", $product_id, time()+ (30),'/');
echo $shortlist_count_c = count($_COOKIE['cookie_product']);
if (isset($_COOKIE['cookie_product'][$s_id])) {

    echo "blah blah";
}

setcookie("shortlist_count", $shortlist_count_c, time()+ (30),'/');
```

The problem is I can see that cookie is being set on my browser under resources tab as `"cookie_product[111]" => "222"` on `first click on "add to shortlist"` but the count gets updated `only after second click on "add to shortlist"`.

Comment: Have you thought about using `sessionStorage` - in conjunction with json it would be far simpler to implement without requiring ajax calls and cookies..

Answer (score 0):

[Read documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array.

Try this:

```
$shortlist_count_c = count($_COOKIE['cookie_product']) + 1;
```

Comment: This will fail if a particular product is already stored in cookie and user clicks on the product multiple times.

Comment: Yes, of course, but this is simplest solution. Сertainly you should add addtioinal checks (on client and server side) related to application logic. For example - you can check cookies on client side, and don't send ajax request if product now stored in cookies. This checks can be (or should be) duplicated on the server side.

Comment: My answer was to - "but the count gets updated only after second click on "add to shortlist" ".  When you count cookeis, there doesn't exists last changes.